# Warning when loading natbib and backref

Tags: hyperref, natbib, backref

The following codes work well without using `natbib`. However, when I use `natbib`, `backref` doesn't work and a warning is given. Is there any way to solve this problem?

`test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[backref]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \cite{latexcompanion}
    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    \bibliography{sample}
\end{document}
```

`sample.bib`:

```
@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
```

Warning:

```
File `test.brf' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck) Rerun to get bibliographical references right.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do what it says: rerun the document. After

```
pdflatex 
bibtex
pdflatex
pdflatex
pdflatex
```

your example run without warning and I got

[image]

Use `\usepackage[backref=page]{hyperref}` if you want a backref to the page. By default the backref goes to the structure and so here to "document" as you have no section.

Comment: Great solution! And I would be grateful if you can tell me why I need to execute the pdflatex command one more time.